# ForceBuild concern with this scenario - CruiseControl.NET

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, build-process, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I have three projects in question, lets call them A, B and C. Where 'A' just prepares a cetain build scenario for B, which is the main build. C cleans up the scenario and basically resets B to its original state. 
I have set these projects in the same queue, and tested this process for the most part works excecpt when Project B fails. Here is the situation, which is explained below.

```
<project name="A" queue="main">
    <publishers>
     <email status of build/>
      <forcebuild>
        <project>B</project>
      </forcebuild>
      <forcebuild>
        <project>C</project>
      </forcebuild>
       </publishers>
   <task>Prepares special scenario</task>
 </project>
 <project name="B" queue="main">
   <publishers>
   </publishers>
    <task>Builds main project</task>
 </project>
 <project name="C" queue="main">
   <publishers>
   </publishers>
    <task>Resets special scenario</task>
 </project>
```

Scenarios:

1. When project 'A' is forced, it builds project B, if B is successful, it builds C. This works fine.
2. When project 'A' is forced, it builds project 'B', if B fails, it builds C. This is also fine in my case.
3. Now after number 2 scenario and bug are fixed in Project B; if project A is forced once more and project B displays a cruise status of 'fixed', it DOES NOT build C. This is NOT fine?

Can anyone see that reason why project C will not build if a combination of No.2 and No.3 is happens? Any help or direction is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always clean up your test environment after you are done with it. I would recommend using the [project trigger](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Trigger) for project C and set it up something akin to the following. This will allow C to always run if A is successful (can be changed by modifying the project trigger in C).

```
<project name="A" queue="main">
    <publishers>
     <email status of build/>
     <forcebuild>
       <project>B</project>
     </forcebuild>
   </publishers>
   <tasks>Prepares special scenario</tasks>
 </project>

 <project name="B" queue="main">
 ...
 </project>

 <project name="C" queue="main">
   <triggers>
     <projectTrigger project="A" />
   </triggers>
   <publishers />
   <tasks>Resets special scenario</tasks>
 </project>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. The funny thing is I was not able to re-create my scenarios initial stated on my local server. Both my method and the one you suggested works as expected. But moving forward i will adopt the use of the ProjectTrigger as it seems to be the cleaner way to handle these situations. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Can project `A` be responsible for cleaning up the current state and preparing for the new build.

Say for example there was a power failure part way through `B`'s build. In this configuration you would need to manually force `C` to be able to run the build process?

If `A` runs the same tasks as `C`, then as own task, this would remove this problem and yours too I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose project A can be responsible for both, but A needs to be successful so B can build and C should only be built after B. This is why C is a separate project. Since A, B and C are in the same queue B will always be built before C if A is forced.....  Can you explain a little more exactly what you mean by "If A runs the same tasks as C, then it's own task," ?

Comment: You should always clean up your environment after a test case is run. Therefore, you should always run C in order to get yourself back to a valid state.

Comment: @Jerome. I've fixed the grammar, sorry for the confusion

Comment: True, you should always do your best to clean up the environment after a build. However you should also cater for the scenario where some outside force leaves the environment in a weird state. The only way to resolve this is to clean up before also.

Comment: Outside forces can be as mundane as a power failure,  someone clicks' abort' etc